# COM interface can't be found in registry after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, com, windows-10, registry

I have an old MFC/ATL appilcation that was originally developed in Visual Studio 2002 (Win XP). It works perfectly in Windows 7 and older but can't run in Windows 10 because I get internal app error caused by COM interface declared in one of the dll of this app can't be found in Windows registry.

Verification of interface is registered is implemented with following function:

```
// IID_INamedData - GUID of custom interface of this app
CheckInterface(GetControllingUnknown(), IID_INamedData); 

inline bool CheckInterface( IUnknown *punkn, const GUID guid )
{
    if( punkn )
    {
        IUnknown    *ptest = nullptr;

        // this equation leads to false and following described error
        if( punkn->QueryInterface( guid, (void**)&ptest ) ==S_OK )
        {
            ptest->Release();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I can compile the .exe with entry point of this app in Visual Studio 2022 and debug it but still get error in code above.

Also I've tried to install this app in Win 7 and upgrade to Win 10, but it didn't help -
the app stopped working after upgrade (OS registries look the same)

Comment: Did you install and register the server app that implements the COM object you are trying to access?

Comment: And more importantly, install it with the same bitedness as the program that is looking for the COM object. There are actually two sets of COM entries in the registry, one for 32-bit binaries, the other for 64-bit.

Comment: A call to `QueryInterface()` doesn't reach to the registry. Nothing needs to be registered. It's just calling into the implementation passed in.

Comment: At any rate, the issue is with the `QueryInterface()` implementation. You need to show that code instead of the code that calls it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My app have installer. During installation it registers all interfaces and classes implemented in ocx and dll related to the app. The installer reports successfully registration both in Win 7 and in Win 10 (register entries seem identical after installation in Win 7 and in Win 10 after upgrading the same PC OS). But the app can't find these entries in Win 10. So maybe something changed in interaction mechanism with registry after Win 7...

Comment: @SoronelHaetir The records of these COM entries seem identical in Win 7 and Win 10. My app is 32-bit, but can work in 64-bit Win 7 system. In both OS records are placed in SysWOW64 related location.

Comment: @IInspectable As far as I understand in code above QueryInterface called by IUnknown pointer that implementation is standard. I'm not very familiar with COM technology... Anyway this app works in Windows 7, but not in Windows 10. What difference might be possible in these systems?

Comment: Nothing stops `QueryInterface()` from returning a pointer to a new object rather than a pointer to the current object. If `GetControllingUnknown()` does not return null, but querying `INamedData` fails, that could imply such behavior to happening internally.

Comment: @MarkF Your app is 32bit, but is the installer also 32bit, or is it 64bit? HOW does the installer register the libs? Does it manipulate the Registry directly, or does it call into the libs to register themselves (ie, with regsvr32)?

Comment: *"that implementation is standard"* - There is no standard `QueryInterface()` implementation. Every COM object provides a **custom** `IUnknown` interface implementation. If `QueryInterface()` fails, step through it in a debugger to learn why. Make sure to read through [COM Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-fundamentals) if you don't have previous experience with the technology.